# Html Images not displayed in QLPreviewController

Tags: html, objective-c, image, printing, qlpreviewcontroller

I am using QLPreviewController to show an html page to print it. After QLPreviewController loads the html, images are not displayed however they are displaying normally when i open it via browser.Can anyone have an idea why the images wont display in the QLPreviewController view

Code :

thanks in Advance

Comment: <img src=file:///Users/softech/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/AAAC0AD7-C18A-4D42-8FEF-9755F257ED78/Documents/Members/1.png width=100 height=100 />

Comment: I think you must provide 'px' to your width and height:

Comment: it did not work ..it show empty image with border well defined according to width and height but there is not image.

Comment: <img src="file:///Users/softech/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/A‌​pplications/AAAC0AD7-C18A-4D42-8FEF-9755F257ED78/Documents/Members/1.png" width="100px" height="100px" />